# Confused between 2 implementations of a sentence in first order logic

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I was reading a book where the author converts the sentence

> Everyone who loves all animals is loved by someone

to this logical sentence:

```
∀x [∀y Animal(y) => Loves(x, y)] => [∃z Loves(z, x)
```

However I came up with this logic, which's different:

```
∀x [∀y Animal(y) ∧ Loves(x, y)] => [∃z Loves(z, x)]
```

Note however that the next sentence, is converted similar to second version one instead of the first version. So going by the previous example, why is the sentence

> Anyone who kills an Animal is loved by no one

converted to

```
∀x [∃y Animal(y) ∧ Kills(x, y)] => [∀z ¬Loves(z, x)]
```

instead of this:

```
∀x [∃y Animal(y) => Kills(x, y)] => [∀z ¬Loves(z, x)
```

I'm confused as to why we pick one over the other. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Your clause "$\forall y$ $Animal(y)$ $\wedge$ [stuff]" doesn't mean what you want it to; it means "Every $y$ **is** an animal and [stuff]." Presumably your universe has things in it which are not animals. "Every animal [stuff]" is different from "Everything is an animal and [stuff]."

Comment: @NoahSchweber So why would the second sentence not use the same format of using => instead of ∧

Comment: Because the quantifier involved is different in each case. Think about the difference between "There is something which is an animal *and* belongs to me" versus "There is something which, if it is an animal, belongs to me." The former basically says I have a pet; the latter says literally nothing if we accept that there are things which aren't animals. $\forall$ and $\exists$ require different Boolean operations to form their corresponding "bounded" versions (e.g. "Every animal" and "Some animal" respectively); see also [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4032285/28111).

Comment: [This summary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232992/21813) confirms that your book is correct on both counts. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3587419/21813) are two more explanations in addition to Noah's above link.